# How can I create an image of a partition (ext4) and later mount it to browse/restore files?

Tags: mount, backup, restore, clone

I'd like to backup my current Debian 9 server OS partition so I can install a clean version of Debian 10.

However, after installing Debian 10, I'd like to mount my old OS image so I can browse and restore files as needed.

I thought I would use CloneZilla but apparently you can't directly mount the images that it creates?

Comment: is `debootstrap` an option? if you're happy with your current filesystem layout and enough free space available, you could get away without deleting/formatting anything (debootstrap to subdir, then switch)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As root, just `cat` the partition to another partition: `cat /dev/sdXn > /dev/sdYi`

or to a file:  `cat /dev/sdXn > backup.img`

Or to a file or partition on another machine: `cat /dev/sdXn | ssh user@host 'cat > backup.img'`

You could use `dd` instead of `cat`, but there's no good reason to do so:

```
dd if=/dev/sdXn of=backup.img
```

Or if you want a progress bar while it's copying and/or control over how much buffering is used during the copy, you could use `pv`:

```
pv /dev/sdXn > backup.img
```

If the partition has read-errors, you might want to use `ddrescue` instead of `cat`:

```
ddrescue /dev/sdXn /dev/sdYi
```

or

```
ddrescue /dev/sdXn backup.img
```

`ddrescue` won't write to stdout (or read from stdin, either), so if you want that `backup.img` on another machine, you'll have to copy it (e.g. with `scp`)  afterwards, or write it to an NFS mount.

Or, as mentioned by user1133275 in a comment, you could use [process substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_substitution):

```
ddrescue /dev/sdXn >(ssh user@host 'cat > backup.img')
```

---

Finally, if you want a compressed, mountable filesystem you could use `qemu-img`:

```
qemu-img convert -c -O qcow2 /dev/sdXn backup.qcow2
```

To mount it:

```
qemu-nbd --connect=/dev/nbd0 /path/to/backup.qcow2
mount /dev/nbd0 /mnt
```

Both `qemu-img` and `qemu-nbd` are in the `qemu-utils` package.   BTW, if you took an image of the entire disk rather than just a partition, you could run your old system as a VM in your new system.

---

Another alternative is just to install a second disk and install the Debian 10 on that.  Then you can just mount the old drive somewhere on the new system.   Or even dual-boot between Debian 9 and Debian 10.

---

Personally, I would recommend a file copy (e.g. with `tar` or `rsync` or even `cp -a`) rather than an image backup.  It's more useful, can be extracted easily to anywhere you want, and doesn't waste space or time copying empty or unused sectors.

image backup are (almost always) the worst way to backup a filesystem.

Comment: Thanks so much!  It looks like there are a bunch of options.  I asked in the above comment as well, but I'll also ask here:  Is it possible to compress the image but still be able to mount it without having to extract/decompress it first?

Comment: Not unless the image file is on a filesystem that supports transparent compression - e.g. btrfs or ZFS.

Comment: on second thoughts, you could probably convert the raw disk image to a .qcow2 image (which are often used for VMs).  or a squashfs (often used for live CDs).   both of those support compression, and can be mounted.

Comment: ddrescue /dev/sdXn >(ssh user@host 'cat > backup.img')

Comment: yep, process subst. would work.

Comment: squashfs worked great.  thanks!

Answer (score 6):

`e2image` can be used to create an image of an ext4 file system, while only copying sectors which are in use:

```
e2image -ra /dev/sda1 /path/to/file.img
```

`file.img` will be created as a sparse file, so it will only occupy the space which is really used in the file system, even though its apparent size will reflect the capacity of the file system. It can be mounted directly, like any file system image:

```
mount /path/to/file.img /path/to/mountpoint
```

You can also use `e2image` to produce a QCOW2 image:

```
e2image -Qa /dev/sda1 /path/to/file.qcow2
```

This will produce a compact file which can still be mounted, using `qemu-nbd`:

```
qemu-nbd --connect=/dev/nbd0 /path/to/file.qcow2
mount /dev/nbd0 /path/to/mountpoint
```

Both images can be compressed, although that results in a file which can’t be mounted directly.

Comment: nice, i wasn't aware of e2image.

Comment: I suggest this answer updated to address the second half of the question:  how to restore from the image?  (especially the first "-ra" case, as I'm not finding any answer searching the web)

Comment: @NoahR the first image can be mounted directly. I’ve added instructions for both scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

having your ext4 partition mounted as `/whatever`

```
mkisofs -o    /somehwere_else/whatever.iso    /whatever
```

now you have a however large *whatever.iso*.  You will obviously have to be mindful of disk space for where you move it around to.

to access that iso you would simply do

```
mount -o loop /somewhere/whatever.iso   /anywhereyoulike/mywhateveriso/
```

everything that was under your folder `/whatever` would now be accessible **read-only** under `/anywhwereyoulike/mywhateveriso/`

The fact that you have an `ext4` partition is almost irrelevant, because you will be dumping that data into a *container* which will be in a *different filesystem format*.  So whether it was data in an ext4 or xfs or btrfs partition does not matter because at that point you already have linux kernel filesystem support to access it in the first place.

Once you have your data in that iso container via **mkisofs** which is pretty universal, that data can now be accessed from nearly anywhere because isofs is universal... *if your computer can read a cd/dvd [iso9660/udf] then you'll be able to access your whatever.iso.  Doing a .iso will make it very portable.*

using `cat` or `tar` or `dd` will preserve the file system which may be problematic