# How to use dd for only allocated space?

Tags: backup, dd, parted

I want to backup whole disk using DD.
I have a 512 Gb disk with 3 partitions who take only 8 Gb and the rest is unused.

```
root@routerMARS:~# parted  /dev/sda print
Model: ATA MT-512 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 512GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name  Flags
128     17.4kB  262kB   245kB                      bios_grub
 1      262kB   17.0MB  16.8MB  fat16              legacy_boot
 2      17.0MB  8000MB  7983MB  ext2
```

I want to backup it using something like

```
dd if=/dev/sda bs=4M conv=noerror | pv | gzip -c > /mnt/backupusb/sda.img.gz
```

So, I need to backup using `dd` with `count=$(( 8000 / 4 ))` as I assume?

I did the following:

```
DD_DISK=/dev/sda  
SAVE_FILE=/mnt/backupusb/sda.img.gz  
DD_BS=4194304 # 4 MB  
DISK_LEN=$(parted --script --json ${DD_DISK} unit B print | jq '.disk.partitions | map(.end) | [.[]|rtrimstr("B")|tonumber] | max')  
DD_COUNT=$(( (DISK_LEN + DD_BS - 1) / DD_BS )) # "DD_BS - 1" is to round up division

sync
dd if=${DD_DISK} bs=${DD_BS} count=${DD_COUNT} conv=noerror | pv --buffer-size ${DD_BS} --size ${DISK_LEN} --rate-limit 50M | gzip -c > ${SAVE_FILE}
```

Please advice if it seems correct?

Comment: [don't use `dd conv=noerror`](https://superuser.com/a/1075837/195171). it will give you corrupt data if there is actually a read error. stick with `ddrescue` for imaging faulty devices.  if you must use dd, also add `iflag=fullblock`.

Comment: See also [`e2image`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/541414/86440) if you would like to copy only those sectors of the second partition which are actually in use.

Comment: "_I want to backup whole disk using `dd`_" - why would you want to use one of the most error prone and complicated solutions for a backup?

Comment: See this thread & particularly post #6 by TheFu: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2465713 & https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem & 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CategoryBackupRecovery  Better to use rsync, not dd
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1331348/can-i-use-dd-to-back-up-a-mounted-partition

Comment: I would consider taking copies of the partitions (+ the partition table), instead of a partial image of the whole drive. It'd be clearer that way, and for GPT, you need to fix the backup copy of the partition table at the end if the disk anyway.

Comment: This is an XY problem.  You can't get `dd` to do what you want because it wasn't designed for that.  You should use a correct backup tool instead.

Comment: If this is a live disk (i.e. it's in use) you will either see it's given you a bad backup or worse you'll fail to notice until you need to restore it. You cannot safely use `dd` or any other non-locking image solution with a live disk and expect to have a decent backup

Comment: I would suggest using [Clonezilla](https://clonezilla.org), to create a live Clonezilla system in a USB drive, boot from it and let it create a Clonezilla image (a directory with several files, that can be restored to the same drive or a new drive with at least the same size). See also [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/958242/fastest-way-to-copy-hdd/958248#958248).